# Resize Drupal Block under Contact Form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

We have a Drupal 7 site and I need to add some simple text under the 'send message in the contact form section.  The problem is that if I create a new block and add it under the contact form it displays far below the contact form.

How can I make the text show directly below the contact form?

This is what it looks like when I add the block:
This is what happens when I try to add a new block under the contact form. http://andtheangelcried.com/images/new_block.jpg

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webform module for that contact form you can add new field in "markup" type, which is not collecting any data from user, but just displays html. But even adding new static block should work - you just have to adjust CSS.